# [Unhandled promise rejection: FirebaseError: No document to update: projects/donate-83e96/databases/(default)/documents/

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I'm using react native and firebase, so when I update the user profile I get the above error any idea how to solve it?

User Profile Code:

```
import {db,auth} from '../../firebase'

    const EditProfile=({navigation})=>{
    
      const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
      const [uploading,setUploading] = useState(false)
      const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);
    
      {/*retrieve data from firestore*/}
    
       React.useEffect(()=>{
        const getUserData = async()=>{
    
          db.collection("users")
          .doc(auth.currentUser?.uid)
          .get()
          .then(snap => {
          
              setUserData(snap.data());
            
          });
        }
        getUserData();
      },[])
    
     const updateProfile = async()=>{
        let imgUrl = await uploadImage();
        if(imgUrl == null && userData.userImg){
         imgUrl = userData.userImg
        }
    
        db.collection("users")
        .doc(auth.currentUser.uid)
        .update({
          name: userData.name,
          email: userData.email,
          phone: userData.phone,
          address: userData.address,
          userImg:userData.imgUrl
          
      })
      }
    
    
      {/*upload Image to firebase sotrage*/}
    
       const uploadImage = async ()=>{
          if(image == null){
            return "";
          }
          const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onload = function (){
               resolve(xhr.response)
            };
            xhr.onerror = function (){
                reject( new TypeError("Network request failed"))
    
            };
            xhr.responseType = "blob"
            xhr.open("GET",image,true)
            xhr.send(null)
          });
          const ref = firebase.storage().ref().child("images/" + new Date().toISOString())
          const snapshot = ref.put(blob)
    
          snapshot.on(
            firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
            ()=>{
                setUploading(true)
            },
            (error)=>{
                setUploading(false)
                console.log(error)
                blob.close();
                return ;
            },
            ()=>{
                snapshot.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url)=>{
                  
                  setUserData({...userData, imgUrl: url})
                  setUploading(false);
                   // Alert.alert('Profile Updated', 'You profile Updated Successfully..!')
                    console.log('donwload:', url)
                    blob.close()
                    return null
                })
            }
          )
       
        
           
        
         }
        function renderDetails(){
         return(
            <View>
                {/*edit name*/}
              <View>
              <TextInput 
                 placeholder="Name"
                 placeholderTextColor='#66666666'
                 autoCorrect={false}
                 value={userData ? userData.name : ''}
                 onChangeText={(txt) => setUserData({...userData, name: txt})}
                 style={{
                    paddingLeft:5,
                    color:'#05375a'
                 }}
            />
    
           </View>   
    
                {/*edit email*/}  
                <View>
                  <TextInput 
                      placeholder="Email"
                      placeholderTextColor='#66666666'
                      keyboardType="email-address"
                      autoCorrect={false}
                      value={userData ? userData.email : ''}
                      onChangeText={(txt) => setUserData({...userData, email: txt})}
                     style={{
                        paddingLeft:5,
                        color:'#05375a' 
                     }}
                  />   
                </View>   
                {/* edit phone number and the address same textInput as name and email*/} 
                 
                 {/*Update Button*/}  
                 {!uploading ?
                 <View>
                   <AppButton 
                     label="Update"
                    onPress={updateProfile}
                   />
                 </View> 
                  :<UploadProgress />
                }
```

So after I login I go to user profile screen to fill in the user details and press update profile button I get the above error that there is not document to update and this happened after the firestore free trial been expired but before I can update the screen smoothly

Comment: try replace `.update({...})` with `.set({...}, { merge: true })`

Comment: thanks a lot it is working with `.set`,but before was working with `.update` . I'm just wondering why ?

Comment: since no document exists both update will give an error and set will create them again

Comment: can i move the comment out to the answer?

Comment: yes you can because your answer is helpful go ahead plead

Answer (score 0):

replace `.update({...})` with `.set({...}, { merge: true })`